# Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL

Tags: jsp, exception, query-string, paging

Inside my jsp page, I have links that contain different querystring. I used it mainly for paging purpose.

```
<a href='/test?page=1&code=${code}'>Page 1</a>
<a href='/test?page=2&code=${code}'>Page 2</a>
<a href='/test?page=3&code=${code}'>Page 3</a>
```

When I first load into this jsp page, everything works fine. The moment I clicked on any of the links, I will get the error below.

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxx&scope=user_photos&redirect_uri=http://xxx.herokuapp.com/test&client_secret=xxx&code=xxx
```

I am wondering if this error is linked to my querystring? Is there a way to workaround this issue as I really need the paging in my jsp page?

Inside my servlet...

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String code = req.getParameter("code");
    String page = req.getParameter("page");

    if(page == null){
        page = "1";
    }

    String MY_ACCESS_TOKEN = "";

    String redirect = "http://xxx.herokuapp.com/test";
    String en_redirect = URLEncoder.encode(redirect, "UTF-8");
    String en_code = URLEncoder.encode(code, "UTF-8");

    String authURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=xxx&scope=user_photos&redirect_uri=" + en_redirect + "&client_secret=xxx&code="
            + code;

    URL url = new URL(authURL);
    String result = readURL(url);
    String[] pairs = result.split("&");

    for (String pair : pairs) {
        String[] kv = pair.split("=");
        if (kv[0].equals("access_token")) {
            MY_ACCESS_TOKEN = kv[1];
        }
    } // end of for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to HTML encode the value of the parameter redirect_uri. This is the process that turns special characters into % followed by a hex number. Like space becomes %20. This will be important for encoding the ampersands that are part of the second URL rather than the primary one.

```
 parameter = java.net.URLEncoder.encode( parameter );
```

Its good practice to do this for all the parameters, especially if they might contain an ampersand in them.

Comment: I have added that to my existing code but I still get the same error. I have updated the code in my first post, did I miss out anything? Thanks.